# List still being treated as a set even after converting

Tags: machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

So i have an instance where even after converting my sets to lists, they  aren't recognized as lists.

So the idea is to delete extra columns from a data frame comparing with columns in another. I have two data frames say df_test and df_train . I need to remove columns in df_test which are not in train .

```
 extracols = set(df_test.columns) - set(df_train.columns) #Gives cols 2b 
                                                            deltd
 l = [extracols]       # or  list(extracols)                                                         
 Xdp.dropna( subset = l, how ='any'  , axis = 0)
```

I get an error : Unhashable type set
Even on printing l it prints like a set with {} curlies.

Comment: Can you please provide more code to give the snippet you've provided better context. Also, can you please make clearer what it is you are asking. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

[{set}] doesn't cast to list, it just creates a list of length 1 with your set inside it.

Are you sure that list({set}) isn't working for you? Maybe you should post more of your code as it is hard to see where this is going wrong for you.

Comment: cols_test   = df_test.columns
              cols_train  = df_train.columns
              extracols = set(cols_test) - set(cols_train)
              l = list(extracols)
              Xdp.dropna( subset = l , how ='any'  , axis = 0)